# chrome keep using old password for website

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome stored my password for booking.com
Later I've changed password for booking.com
But chrome keep using old password so every time I have to enter new password.

How to force chrome to use updated password for booking.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Chrome to the newest version. Now go to the *Settings* <kbd>→</kbd> *Show Advance Settings* <kbd>→</kbd> *Manage Passwords* and delete the old password. Now go to the site, enter your credentials and click at the prompt save password. Now the new password will be used.

Comment: thanks, it works, but why chorme doesn't replace password automatically? once I enter new password I expect chrome to replace it in database..

Comment: well it saves all the different passwords you used on the same site. That is the case by me. It does not replace the password automatically because you might make a mistake and than the false credentials would be saved. I might be wrong about this.